# Creation tables for CKAN in public schema

Tags: database, postgresql, ckan

When installing CKAN, when the process creates the database tables in PostgreSQL, these are created in a public scheme, ¿why not create them in the schema specified (ckan_default)? ¿can the use of a public scheme cause security problems?

We are installing CKAN in a shared bd and all users will have access to the public scheme. ¿Are there other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql docs say:

> A database contains one or more named schemas, which in turn contain
>   tables

So if you have non-CKAN users in your Postgresql cluster then simply deny them access to the CKAN database.

Your question suggests you need to give them access to the CKAN database, but not to some of the tables - you'll need to explain that.

Alternatively you've misunderstood and think that there is one "public" schema shared across all the databases, whereas the docs are confirm that is incorrect:

> By default, such tables (and other objects) are automatically put into a 
>   schema named "public". Every new database contains such a schema.